# How to resolve required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting the below error:

```
equired a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] 
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] The injection point has the following annotations:
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] 
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] 
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] Action:
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] 
08-Dec-2021 06:49:02      [sshexec] Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Below are my classes:

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    List<AmazonSNS> amazonSNSClientArray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public List<AmazonSNS> amazonSnsClient() {
        
    }

}
```

Can someone help me to resolve the issue? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You most likely have defined a Spring bean with a constructor that takes a `String` as a parameter. Spring is trying to find a `String` in the application context to pass to that constructor. Solution: Don't define a constructor that needs a `String` in your Spring bean, or make sure that that `String` value can be found (for example by using a `@Value` annotation on the parameter, pointing to the appropriate source).

Comment: The error does not match your code. You seem to be trying to inject a `String` using `@Autowired` but your code shows nothing that resembles this. Please edit your question and add the relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question and added the relevant code

Comment: Your `genericProvisioningAWSCredentials` bean method expects 2 strings. As you haven't defined those as to come from a property (with an `@Value`) spring will try to autowire those parameters using beans. As there are no beans of type string this will obviously fail. Looking at your code that method is more of a helper method than a bean method, remove `@Bean` from that method.

Comment: How can I resolve it? Sorry, I'm new to spring boot.

Comment: Please close or delete this question

Comment: @SwetaSharma you can delete your own question(s)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the following code snippet:

```java
@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProvider genericProvisioningAWSCredentials(String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretKeyId) {     
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKeyId));
}
```

This will instruct Spring to inject two `String`s which you seem to not have defined as Spring-managed Beans.

It seems to me that you don't actually need `AWSCredentialsProvider` as a Spring-managed Bean (you are just using this method to build the `AmazonSNSClientBuilder` in the method above), so just drop `@Bean` annotation and make the method private:

```java
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private ReadAwsApplicationProperties readAwsApplicationProperties;
    
    List<AmazonSNS> amazonSNSClientArray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public List<AmazonSNS> amazonSnsClient() {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < readAwsApplicationProperties.getEnv().size(); i++) 
        {
            amazonSNSClientArray.add(AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(readAwsApplicationProperties.getEnv().get(i).getGeneric().getProv().getAws().getRegion())
                .withCredentials(genericProvisioningAWSCredentials(readAwsApplicationProperties.getEnv().get(i).getGeneric().getProv().getAws().getAccessKeyId(), readAwsApplicationProperties.getEnv().get(i).getGeneric().getProv().getAws().getAwsSecretKeyId()))
                .build());
        }
        logger.info(" The size of sns client is " + amazonSNSClientArray.size());
        return amazonSNSClientArray;
    }
    
    private AWSCredentialsProvider genericProvisioningAWSCredentials(String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretKeyId) {     
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKeyId));
    }
}
```

Comment: I made above changes now  it  gives : required a bean of type 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider' that could not be found. error Could you please help

Comment: Where are you using `AWSCredentialsProvider` other than here? Or is it some autoconfiguration kicking in?

Comment: some autoconfiguration kicking in

Comment: You edited your question and basically removed all the code. Was this intentional?

Comment: I'm soory! It just I'm panicked not sure how to resolve that error and I need to submit ot urhently

Comment: Without additional details, we can't help you further. The code that I have in my answer should work with the information that we have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239950/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-joao-dias).